# IF clause is not being detected in XSL script

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have this simple template:

```
  <!--Item-->
  <xsl:template match="Presentations|TFGWItem">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Theme"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Name" />
    </tr>

    <xsl:if test="name()='Presentations'">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

But the `if` clause  is not processing. Am I doing the `if` test incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried local-name? Could be a namespace problem

Comment: @fafl I know that my "<Presentations>" node is being processed because the first bit works. What is `local-name`?

Comment: name() contains the namespace prefix (e.g. "xsl" or "d") and local-name doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the test was working. It was just that the empty rows were not getting displayed in the browser.

I had to change it:

```
  <!--Item-->
  <xsl:template match="LACItem|Presentations|TFGWItem">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Theme"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Name" />
    </tr>

    <xsl:if test="name()='Presentations'">
      <tr>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&#160;</td>
        <td>&#160;</td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```